# Split an image into parts

Tags: java, image-processing, javax.imageio

I know that there are a lot of topics about this, but none really fits into my problem.
I need the attached image ([link](http://www.bilder-hochladen.net/files/big/1fby-6t-555d.png)) divided into multiple sub-images and I search for the easiest way to do this.

The image should be saveable. I tried BufferedImage, which lacks a useful constructor for this.

It doesn't have to be java. A simple tool who can do this would also do the job. Note: I have to get ~567 images out of one. I found "online image-splitters", but none was able to split the image into more than 32 parts.

Comment: what about http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)?

Comment: @BevynQ I saw this, but the how can I get an image into BufferedImage? I know this method, but it didn't look for me like it could fit my problem. :) Greets

Comment: the easiest way I know is using http://www.imagemagick.org/ - an example here http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=15771

Comment: *"I know that there are a lot of topics about this, but none really fits into my problem"* - Really?  Why is that?  Can you sight examples?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've gone throug several links and I won't warm this up just for evidence. But if you can find a question/tutorial on how to load/split/save multiple fragments, I would be pleased. :)
But since ccjme's answer, thats ok. :)

Comment: @TrudleR With no disrespect intended; how would we know that if the suggest fix by ccjme is right or wrong with out context of what you have tried and why it didn't work. You could have ended up with dozens of answer repeating what had already tried, wasting every bodies times

Comment: @MadProgrammer Dunno, but ccjmne was able to understand what I was asking. Of course I could have blown the question up. But then I'd really wasted everyones time, since this seemed to be enough information for at least one guy. And what if I did the right approach but wasn't able to do it? Should then everyone search for another solution because there is NO WAY that the question-guy did a fault? This question was rhetorical, this discussion shouldn't be hold here anyway. Greets, Trudler (:

Comment: @TrudleR Yes, you got lucky, some "guessed" the solution to your problem (and +1 can ccjme), it would have been the same suggestion I would have given...but context is king ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
final BufferedImage source = ImageIO.read(new File("<sourceDir>/1fby-6t-555d.png"));
int idx = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < source.getHeight(); y += 32) {
    ImageIO.write(source.getSubimage(0, y, 32, 32), "png", new File("<sourceDir>/1fby-6t-555d_" + idx++ + ".png"));
}
```

`:)`

---

**Output:**

[image]